# How Can I count the number of result generated by show directive

Tags: mysql

In Mysql , I want to count the number of result generated by using `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8%';`How
should I write the sql?

Answer (score 1):

You can't using that particular syntax, but you can by querying the `information_schema.collations` table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.collations
WHERE COLLATION_NAME LIKE 'utf8%';
```

Or, this query might be a bit more optimal:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.collations
WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8';
```